# magento 2.0.18 Class Magento\Framework\Intl\NumberFormatterFactory does not exist

Tags: compiler-errors, magento2

when running a command "`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`" I am facing this issue in magento version 2.0.18

```
[ReflectionException]
  Class Magento\Framework\Intl\NumberFormatterFactory does not exist


[ReflectionException]
  Class Magento\Framework\Intl\NumberFormatterFactory does not exist


  [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
  Source class "\Magento\Framework\Intl\NumberFormatter" for "Magento\Framework\Intl\NumberFormatterFactory" generation doe
  s not exist.
```

I know, it's been removed in Magento 2.2.x but I'm using version 2.0.18..

here's the screenshot:
[image]

any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

please run below command 
sudo chmod -R 777 var/